# Is there unique_from_this()? Or how return unique_ptr from class inherited from enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I want my builder method `Class::create()` to return the `unique_ptr`

Why?

1) This design is not enforcing the shared ownership (and atomic lock). `unique_ptr` is very efficient and has same size as `void*`

2) Still, it is easy to move to `shared_ptr` **on the class user's side** (but only when client would like to share the instance for multiple ownership)

So. I want to pay only for what I'm using

But. I need some class instance's methods to return "this" pointer.
If I inherit class from `enable_shared_from_this` I just use `return shared_from_this` but I think it won't be related to the unique ownership

In other words,
will the unique_ptr created somewhere in class (without using shared_from_this() of course) somehow be related to (potential) shared_ptr created from this unique_ptr? Or it will lead to double deletion problem?

Comment: TBH I am not sure this make much sense because `this` can easily be put into a `unique_ptr` and there is no problem to solve like there is with `shared_ptr`.

Comment: So let's see - I return the unique_ptr so some Owner class. Then it moves to the shared_ptr and gives the handle to other classes like OtherOwner so they keep strong shared reference. But how can I even find this shared group from the class instance itself?

Comment: This doesn't make any semantic sense. If there is an object to invoke this member function on, then it's already owned by *something*. How can you obtain a unique owner for it in the general case?

Comment: @StoryTeller It does. For example, I create Widgets inside a Controller class. And I want a Widget to be able to create hierarchy. So I build Widget with: `shared_ptr widget1 = move(Widget::create())`. Then auto child = widget1->createChild()  where each child should receive parent's shared_ptr -> to be converted in weak_ptr inside the Child. This means that in createChild I have to access to shared_from_this()

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I know, a bit late, but: IMO, the actual question is: Is enable_shared_from this itself often used at the wrong places in terms of software design? The issue with shared_from_this is: It somehow forces the way a struct/class has to be used (intrusive) and this overlaps with the "inner" semantic meaning of classes. It's fast to tag classes with enable_shared_from_this, but it becomes messy as hell in doubt to re-design things as soon as you want to use the class within different context ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In other words, will the unique_ptr created somewhere in class (without using shared_from_this() of course) somehow be related to (potential) shared_ptr created from this unique_ptr? Or it will lead to double deletion problem?

`shared_ptr` constructors will detect your publicly accessible `enable_shared_from_this` base, so yes, if the `unique_ptr` properly releases its pointer you'll have no double deletion and the `shared_from_this()` member will work correctly (but you'll get UB if the client invokes it with no existing shared_ptr managing it):

```
auto unique = Class::create();
auto shared = std::shared_ptr<Class>{ std::move(unique) }; // ok, pass ownsership to shared
auto shared_again = shared->shared_from_this(); // ok

auto unique2 = Class::create();
auto badly_shared = unique2->shared_from_this(); // nope, UB
auto badly_shared_again = std::shared_ptr<Class>{ unique2.get() }; // nope, double deletion coming ...
```

Moreover, since C++17 `shared_from_this()` will throw `bad_weak_ptr` when invoked from an non-shared instance.

Comment: I see. So unique ownership is not related to shared  (like if I would create just raw * pointer from new). But If I correctly move/convert from unique to shared, the ownership will be correctly maintained and I could use shared_from_this() from the instance. Thanks now it makes sense!

Comment: @barney, yep and from c++17 you even get a nice exception if a client tries to call shared_from_this() when he should not ...

Answer (score 3):

> Is there unique_from_this()?

No.

> Or how return unique_ptr from class inherited from enable_shared_from_this

In general, nothing special has to be done to return a `unique_ptr` to a class inherited from `enable_shared_from_this`. But remember that `shared_from_this` must not be called on instances owned by `unique_ptr`. As such, this is unsafe.

You cannot create a `unique_ptr` to `this` in a safe way, whether `enable_shared_from_this` is inherited or not.

> 1) This design is not enforcing the shared ownership (and atomic lock). `unique_ptr` is very efficient and has same size as `void*`

And this lack of shared ownership, which makes `unique_ptr` fast, is also what makes `unique_from_this` impossible to implement.

Comment: Now its clear, thanks. Once I make a unique ownership its my responsibility as a class client to move it to shared ownership. Then, and only then, the class instance could participate in it by shared_from_this(). In other words, if I want the class to be used flexibly (either by shared or unique builder method) I still could return unique but inherit from enable_shared_from_this class. But then its client's responsibility to move from shared before calling any shared_from_this().